# integrability of periodic functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions

exercise:

A function $f$ is periodic if there exists $T \neq 0$ (a period) such that $f(x+T)=f(x)$ for all $x$. Let $f$ be a periodic function with fundamental period $T$ (that is, $T$ is the lowest positive period, supposing that one such exists). Suppose that $f$ is bounded and integrable on the interval $[0, T]$.

Show that $f$ is integrable on any bounded interval.

My approach:

Let $\varepsilon$ be given, because of integrability of $f$ on the interval $[0, T]$ there is a partition $P$ of that interval satisfies following inequality

$U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\varepsilon$

Let take any bounded interval $[c,d]$ and choose a partition of this interval $P'$ so that each subinterval of $P'$ be lesser than of any subinterval of $P$. In this case we have:

$U(f,P')-L(f,P')<\frac{d-c}{a} \varepsilon$ and from here we can conclude that it is integrable on $[c,d]$

My question:

Is this proof valid?

Comment: We cannot know what your professor appreciates or not.

Comment: @MartinR what about you??)

Comment: Your argument doesn't seem to use the hypothesis that $f$ is periodic. If you don't use this hypothesis, your argument can't possibly be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the acceptable proof with the help of Spivak's book.
We need **theorem 4** and **exercise 12** on the **chapter 13** from Spivak's "Calculus"

**THEOREM 4**: Let $a<c<b$. If $f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$, then $f$ is integrable on $[a, c]$ and on $[c, b]$. Conversely, if $f$ is integrable on $[a, c]$ and on $[c, b]$, then $f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$. Finally, if $f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$, then
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f=\int_{a}^{c} f+\int_{c}^{b} f .
$$
(The proof was given by the author in his book)

**exercise 12**

If $a<b<c<d$ and $f$ is integrable on $[a,d]$ prove that $f$ is integrable on $[b,c]$

proof: Theorem 4, applied to $a<b<d$ implies that  $f$ is integrable on $[b,d]$. Then Theorem 4, applied to $b<c<d$ implies that  $f$ is integrable on $[b,c]$.

Now, because of integrability on $[0,T]$ and periodicity the function $f$ is integrable on $[-T,0], [T,2T], [-2T,-T], [2T,3T], [-3T,-2T]......$

Now, from the above theorems we can conclude that it is integrable on $[-nT,nT]$ $\text{(where n is any natural number)}$ and also integrable on any bounded interval $\blacksquare$